# Problem simulating kinect in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to simulate the turtlebot in gazebo. I am using the turtlebot_gazebo and stack for that (using robot.launch).

However, the depth data coming from the (simulated) kinect is all wrong. Every point in the point cloud published by the /camera/depth/points topic has a depth of 1.0. This is when the light source in the .world file is of the directional kind. When I use a point or spot light source, the bottom half of the pointcloud has depth of 1.0 and the top half either NaN or 1.0 (depending on whether something is within range or not). This is preventing me to use any SLAM algorithm in gazebo. I get the camera rgb image through correctly.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and electric.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12150/problem-simulating-kinect-in-gazebo/) by [Laurie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1472/laurie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Laurie, In general you want a discreet graphics card to run the simulations.  There's a list of user tested cards at http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laurie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1472/laurie/) on 2011-12-21**:
I am using a nVidia card now, and the depth data is correctly simulated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar issue with a depth camera in Gazrbo.  From memory it was caused by the use of texture shadows.  Setting shadows to none in the world file resolved the issue for me.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laurie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1472/laurie/) on 2011-12-08**:
Using lspci I get "Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller"

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-12-08**:
what graphics card do you have?

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-12-03**:
Yes, thats the one I was thinking of.

**Comment by [Laurie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1472/laurie/) on 2011-12-01**:
Do you mean     none and false within the rendering:ogre tag? If so, this solution does not work.